# Find number of rows with each property value, taking into account only the most recent rows in SQL

Tags: sql, join, max, mariadb-10.1

I have a database with tables that represents "edits" to "pages". Every edit has an ID and a timestamp and a "status", which has certain discrete values. Pages have IDs and also have "categories".

I wish to find the number of pages with each status within a given category, taking into account only the state as of the most recent edit.

Edits:

```
+---------+---------+-----------+--------+
| edit_id | page_id | edit_time | status |
+---------+---------+-----------+--------+
| 1       | 10      | 20210502  | 90     |
| 2       | 10      | 20210503  | 91     |
| 3       | 20      | 20210504  | 91     |
| 4       | 30      | 20210504  | 90     |
| 5       | 30      | 20210505  | 92     |
| 6       | 40      | 20210505  | 90     |
| 7       | 50      | 20210503  | 90     |
+---------+---------+-----------+--------+
```

Pages:

```
+---------+--------+
| page_id | cat_id |
+---------+--------+
| 10      | 100    |
| 20      | 100    |
| 30      | 100    |
| 40      | 200    |
+---------+--------+
```

I want to get, for category `100`:

```
+--------+-------+
| stat   | count |
+--------+-------+
| 90     | 1     |
| 91     | 2     |
| 92     | 1     |
+--------+-------+
```

Page `10` and `30` have two edits, but the later one "overrides" the first one, so only the edits with status `91` and `92` are counted. Pages `20` and `40` account for one of `91` and `90` each and page `50` is in the wrong category so it doesn't feature.

I have tried the following, but it doesn't seem to work. The idea was to select the max (i.e. latest) edit for each page with the right category. Then join that to the edit table and group by the status and count the rows:

```
SELECT stat, COUNT(*)
FROM edits as out_e
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT edit_id, page_id, max(edit_time) as last_edit
    FROM edits
    INNER JOIN pages on edit_page_id = page_id
    WHERE cat_id = 100
    GROUP BY page_id
) in_e ON out_e.edit_id = in_e.edit_id
GROUP BY stat
ORDER BY stat;
"""
```

For example in this fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/42f2ed/1

The result is:

```
+--------+-------+
| stat   | count |
+--------+-------+
| 90     | 3     |
| 91     | 1     |
+--------+-------+
```

What is the correct way to get this information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
SELECT cat_id, stat, COUNT(*) cnt
FROM pages
JOIN edits ON pages.page_id = edits.edit_page_id
JOIN ( SELECT edit_page_id, MAX(edit_time) edit_time
       FROM edits
       GROUP BY edit_page_id ) last_time ON edits.edit_page_id = last_time.edit_page_id
                                        AND edits.edit_time = last_time.edit_time
GROUP BY cat_id, stat
```

Output:

| cat_id | stat | cnt |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 90 | 1 |
| 100 | 91 | 2 |
| 100 | 92 | 1 |
| 200 | 90 | 1 |

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=7592c7853481f6b5a9626c8d111c1d3b (the query is applicable to MariaDB 10.1).

---

> Is it possible to join on the edit_id (which is unique key for each edit)? – Inductiveload

No, this is impossible. `cnt=2` counts two different `edit_id` values - what value must be used?

But you may obtain concatenated values list - simply add `GROUP_CONCAT(edit_id)` into the output list.

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=b2391972c3f7c4be4254e47514d0f1da

Answer (score 1):

```
select e1.stat, count(e1.stat) as count 
from edits e1
join (
    select edit_page_id, max(edit_time) as edit_time 
    from edits
    where edit_page_id in (
        select page_id 
        from pages 
        where cat_id = 100
    )
    group by edit_page_id
) as e2
on e1.edit_page_id = e2.edit_page_id and e1.edit_time = e2.edit_time
group by e1.stat;
```

Here's the link to fiddle - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/42f2ed/40/0

Edit: updated to consider edit_time instead of stat to find latest record

Comment: Doesn't this assume that `stat` always increases? The `edit_time` is what I need the max of, not `stat`.

Comment: yes it does assume that, is that not the case, if not then we can do max on `edit_time` and then join with original table to get data, fiddle is having issue, will try and update after some time.

Answer (score 1):

think you dont need the second join - see if the query helps.

```
select
t1.stat, count(*) count_
from
(
SELECT 
  e.edit_id, p.page_id, e.stat,
  rank() over(partition by e.edit_page_id order by e.edit_time desc) edit_rank
FROM 
  edits e
  INNER JOIN pages p on e.edit_page_id = p.page_id
WHERE 
  p.cat_id = 100
) t1
where
t1.edit_rank = 1
group by
t1.stat
```

fiddle url : (https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=0f681dc8d93cc3eebf9a03e0c8d84850)

Comment: Not applicable to OP's server version.